# How do I make this an asynchronous controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, thread-safety

I had a method

```
    public void AddOrUpdateAnswer ( AnswerSubmission Answer, Guid pid )
    {
        this._Conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddOrUpdateAnswer", this._Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerVal", Answer.AnswerVal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionId", Answer.QuestionId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartnerId", pid);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        this._Conn.Close();
    }
```

which I need to convert to an asynchronous task because I found out that it was crashing my web app (502 Bad Gateway) whenever I had more than one user actively submitting answers at a time. So I know that I need to do is make this who thing an asynchronous method. Currently, it gets called by my controller like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitAnswer ( AnswerSubmission Answer, Guid pid)
    {
        bool goodSoFar = true;
        string status = "Answers submitted successfully";
        try
        {
            this._Db.AddOrUpdateAnswer(Answer, pid);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
            status = String.Format("Exception occured during answer submission: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return Json(new { Succeeded = goodSoFar, Message = status });
    }
```

so I think that what I need to do is make that 
like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitAnswer ( AnswerSubmission Answer, Guid pid)
    {
        bool goodSoFar = true;
        string status = "Answers submitted successfully";
        try
        {
            await this._Db.AddOrUpdateAnswer(Answer, pid);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            goodSoFar = false;
            status = String.Format("Exception occured during answer submission: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return Json(new { Succeeded = goodSoFar, Message = status });
    }
```

but then what do I do with `AddOrUpdateAnswer`? I tried changing it to

`public Task AddOrUpdateAnswer`

but then I got the error that not all paths return a value. What am I supposed to return?

Comment: `async` won't change the semantics of your web app. If you get a 502 with sync code, then you'll get a 502 with async code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert your method to async:

```
public async Task AddOrUpdateAnswerAsync ( AnswerSubmission Answer, Guid pid )
    {
        await this._Conn.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddOrUpdateAnswer", this._Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerVal", Answer.AnswerVal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionId", Answer.QuestionId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartnerId", pid);
            await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
        this._Conn.Close();
    }
```

Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details

Comment: You should wrap the connection in a using statement since it implements IDisposable.

Comment: @mason I just take his code and make it async. Don't know why he has a _Conn and not use using

Comment: Yes, but when someone does something dangerous like not ensure a connection gets closed or they open them up to SQL injection attacks, you should consider it your duty to let them know. Also, your syntax is invalid. There is no type `task`.